# Select oldest and newest value from a set of running values

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get the oldest and newest value of a running (for lack of a better term) value in a specified date window with MSSQL 2008 and I'm struggling.  Here's what the table looks like:

```
Job      Date         Percent_complete
---      ----         ----------------
1        1/5/2013     5
2        1/10/2013    5
2        1/25/2013    15
2        2/15/2013    25
3        2/15/2013    5
1        2/10/2013    10
1        2/23/2013    20
1        2/24/2013    18
4        1/12/2013    40
```

For example, in my query, I'd like to ask for the oldest and newest percent_complete for 2/1/2013 - 2/28/2013 and get:

```
Job   Old    New
---   ---    ---
1     5      18
2     15     25
3     0      5
4     40     40
```

...so the catch here is that the last percent_complete value before the start date has to carry forward and if there is no record (such as job 3), it needs to assume 0.  Furthermore, the number may step backwards from it's high, as it did with job 1... so `min(complete)` and `max(complete)` won't get us there.  Also, I've added a record for Job 4 to illustrate the expected result when there's no record in the reporting window.

Comment: If there was an earlier record for Job 3, say, with `Percent_complete` of 4, what should the `Old` value for it read in the output? 0 or 4?

Comment: It depends on the date... if the new record for Job 3 was before 1/15, then `Old` would be still be 5.  If was after 1/15 (but before 2/1) then `Old` would be 4.  Stilling working with the reporting period of 2/1 - 2/28, 0 isn't correct.

Comment: Sorry, I had to be more explicit and not keep half the question in my mind. Let me start over. Currently, your sample contains one row for Job 3, and it's before February. Your requirements prescribe its percentage to go to the `New` column. The corresponding `Old` value is shown as 0, and I'm trying to clarify for myself why specifically in this case it is 0. Is it because the single data row in the source is dated pre-February (i.e. before the required period)? Or is it just because it is a *single* row i.e. it has no predecessor? ...

Comment: So, again, if there was a(nother) Job 3 row, with the `Date` value earlier than the `1/15/2013` (the current Job 3 row also remaining in the set), would `Old` for Job 3 have to remain `0` or would it need to display that other row's `Percent_complete`? (I'm assuming here that `New` would still be 5 either way.)

Comment: And just to save time, my current solution would [show the preceding row's percentage](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92405/1) as `Old` (and 0 if there was no preceding row, like in your present example). @IanPreston's solution, however, would still [show 0](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46be5/1). (I hope Ian gets notified about this comment to be alerted about possible issue with his solution. Although we both would still need your clarification on whether it *is* an issue.)

Comment: OMG!!  You're right!  There's a typo in the data.  The record for Job 3 is supposed to be dated 2/15/13, not 1/15/13 [facepalm].  I'm correcting now.

Comment: Okay, fixed typo and added new Job to show intended result when there's no record in reporting period.  I guess I also have to unaccept Ian's answer.  :(

Comment: The description now seems somewhat out of sync with the example. Or I may still be missing something. However, if I were to consult with the example only, I think I get the logic.

Comment: Which part is out of sync?

Comment: Nothing, sorry, I read something incorrectly. The new Job 4 case isn't explained, though, but, like I said, the logic seems clear (to me, anyway) from the example itself.

Comment: You're right again, I should have clarified what I was doing with Job 4 there, so I added another sentence to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can get the result with something like this:

```
with max_percent as
(
  select Job
    , [Max] = max(Percent_complete)
  from jobs
  where [Date] between '2/1/2013' and '2/28/2013'
  group by Job
),
min_percent as
(
  select Job
    , [Max] = max(Percent_complete)
  from jobs
  where [Date] < '2/1/2013'
  group by Job
)
select Job = coalesce(mn.Job, mx.Job)
  , [Min] = case when mx.Job is not null then mn.[Max] else 0 end
  , [Max] = coalesce(mx.[Max], mn.[Max], 0)
from max_percent mx
  full join min_percent mn on mx.Job = mn.Job
order by Job
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/24f41/6).

But it's a bit difficult to understand your requirements so I'm not sure this will work for your data in all cases. If you add some more data and expected results to the question I can update if required.

**Edit after comment:**

This new query gives the results you're after:

```
with jobList as
(
  select distinct Job from jobs
)
select Job
  , [Min] = isnull(case when mx.[Max] is not null then mn.[Max] else 0 end, 0)
  , [Max] = coalesce(mx.[Max], mn.[Max], 0)

from jobList jl
  outer apply
  (
    select top 1 [Max] = j.Percent_complete
    from jobs j
    where [Date] between '2/1/2013' and '2/28/2013'
      and jl.Job = j.Job
    order by j.[Date] desc
  ) mx
  outer apply
  (
    select top 1 [Max] = j.Percent_complete
    from jobs j
    where [Date] < '2/1/2013'
      and jl.Job = j.Job
    order by j.[Date] desc
  ) mn
order by jl.Job
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29803/9).

Again, it's only against a small dataset, but it takes top values by date instead of just the max percentage so hopefully will get you in the right direction.

**Second edit:**

Just change the query slightly to get your new results:

```
with jobList as
(
  select distinct Job from jobs
)
select Job
  , [Min] = isnull(mn.[Max], 0)
  , [Max] = coalesce(mx.[Max], mn.[Max], 0)

from jobList jl
  outer apply
  (
    select top 1 [Max] = j.Percent_complete
    from jobs j
    where [Date] between '2/1/2013' and '2/28/2013'
      and jl.Job = j.Job
    order by j.[Date] desc
  ) mx
  outer apply
  (
    select top 1 [Max] = j.Percent_complete
    from jobs j
    where [Date] < '2/1/2013'
      and jl.Job = j.Job
    order by j.[Date] desc
  ) mn
order by jl.Job
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84309/3).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll have to look at it closer tomorrow and if it doesn't work I'll add some more sample data.  Basically, I have job status points in a table and I need to find out far jobs have progressed in any given month.  Seems to me that this would be fairly common, but I'm having a heck of time with it.  Maybe there was a better way to store the data...?

Comment: I don't know if it's a *bad* way to store the data... You're recording status updates and want to report a value using them based on a point in time, so it seems logical. Anyway, let me know how the testing goes.

Comment: Thanks for you effort, but I'm now discovering that percent_complete may actually step backwards if something about the job changes.  :(  I've re-worked the question and added another record to the sample data.  Thanks

Comment: I've run it against my data and it seems to be working!  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm sorry, friend... I had a typo in the data so your solution is based on a bad premise.  :(  Job 3 was supposed be dated 2/15/13, not 1/15/13, to end up with those results.  I added another Job record to show intended results in the case that there is no record in the reporting period.  I'm so sorry, I thought I had checked my question thoroughly.

Comment: You only need a slight change to get the required results... Your requirements actually make more sense now, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

**Step 1.** Select rows with `Date` values no later than the selected month, splitting every job's data into two partitions: the selected month data goes into the `New` partition, the rest goes into the `Old` one.

Applied to your example, this would produce the following result set:

```
Job  Date       Percent_complete  recency
---  ----       ----------------  -------
1    1/5/2013   5                 Old    
2    1/10/2013  5                 Old    
2    1/25/2013  15                Old    
2    2/15/2013  25                New    
3    1/15/2013  5                 New    
1    2/10/2013  10                New    
1    2/23/2013  20                New    
1    2/24/2013  18                New    
4    1/12/2013  40                Old
```

**Step 2.** Rank rows in every partition in the descending order of `Date`:

```
Job  Date       Percent_complete  recency  rnk
---  ----       ----------------  -------  ---
1    1/5/2013   5                 Old      1  
2    1/10/2013  5                 Old      2  
2    1/25/2013  15                Old      1  
2    2/15/2013  25                New      1  
3    1/15/2013  5                 New      1  
1    2/10/2013  10                New      3  
1    2/23/2013  20                New      2  
1    2/24/2013  18                New      1  
4    1/12/2013  40                Old      1
```

**Step 3.** Get only rows with the rankings of 1:

```
Job  Date       Percent_complete  recency  rnk
---  ----       ----------------  -------  ---
1    1/5/2013   5                 Old      1
2    1/25/2013  15                Old      1
2    2/15/2013  25                New      1
3    1/15/2013  5                 New      1
1    2/24/2013  18                New      1
```

**Step 4.** Pivot the percentages and default any `Old` NULLs to 0, and `New` to `Old`:

```
Job  Old  New
---  ---  ---
1    5    18
2    15   25
3    0    5
```

The following query implements the above logic:

```
WITH partitioned AS (
  SELECT
    Job,
    Date,
    Percent_complete,
    recency = CASE
      WHEN Date >= '20130201' THEN 'NEW'
      ELSE 'Old'
    END
  FROM atable
  WHERE Date < '20130301'
)
, ranked AS (
  SELECT
    Job,
    Date,
    Percent_complete,
    recency,
    rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Job, recency ORDER BY Date DESC)
  FROM partitioned
)
, filtered AS (
  SELECT
    Job,
    Percent_complete,
    recency
  FROM ranked
  WHERE rnk = 1
)
, pivoted AS (
  SELECT
    Job,
    Old = ISNULL(Old, 0),
    New = ISNULL(New, Old)
  FROM filtered
  PIVOT (
    MAX(Percent_complete) FOR recency IN (Old, New)
  ) u
)
SELECT *
FROM pivoted
;
```

You can test this query [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1d05/1).

Comment: Thanks for your work.  I'll look at it close at the beginning of the week and let you know how it does.

Comment: I didn't pull it apart to figure out why, but it seems to be skipping around 100 of the jobs from the table of about 1500 distinct jobs.  Thanks for all of your help, though.

Comment: It probably skips the newer jobs, those first logged *after* the reporting month. Anyway, if you are keen to just move on, I understand. Besides, the solution you've accepted is shorter/simpler than mine and therefore may be easier to maintain. And even that must be secondary to your just being happy with it (presumably).